# New user having trouble with simple software installation

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation

I downloaded the latest Ubuntu software and installed from flash drive.
I enabled update and within software & updates enabled clicked 4 boxes allowing third party software

I then downloaded binance application for unix from their website, as it was no where to be found in Ubuntu Software application.  It downloaded as a .rpm package.

I would simply like to know how to install this software.  I read I need to install alien and convert from .RPM to Deb format.  Is there another simpler way?

The software is in the 'downloads' folder.  When I run the terminal within the same folder and type 'sudo apt install binance' or binance-x86_64-linux.rpm it simply says unable to locate said package.

I installed alien and when i try to convert the file it simply says not found
I have also ran the synaptics package manager and that too can not find the package even if i rename it and place it on the desktop.

Any help would be much appreciated, as I've already spent several hours to no avail.

Answer (score 3):

You can download it from [here](https://ftp.binance.com/electron-desktop/linux/production/binance-amd64-linux.deb).

It is a  "deb" file, which can be installed locally with the "gdebi package manager"

Please note that this way is not encouraged, since it is inherently insecure. You do not know what code you are downloading and what is does to your system.

Also accept that it might not work, if dependencies are not met. But if you really have to download code like this, look for `.deb` files, not for `.rpm`

Comment: Perfect, installed gdebi package manager and it ran the .deb file.  Thanks for your invaluable help!

Comment: If it helped, you should accept the answer. It shows that the answer is correct and might help others

Answer (score 0):

you can get the .deb package from binance website here
https://www.binance.com/en/download
click on the linux image and it will let you choose either to download an rpm or a deb. Hope it helps.

Comment: Does not add anything to the existing answer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).